# Should I install ibus-1.0 to build Webdriver?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, libraries, pkg-config

In the process of [building one library (Webdriver)](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver) I got the following error:

```
Package ibus-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `ibus-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'ibus-1.0' found
```

It seems to be because of the following line in source code of Webdriver:

```
pkg-config ibus-1.0 --libs
```

that produces the same output when I run it.

So I installed `ibus` [using installation instructions from its website](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-clutter ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-qt4
```

But I still get the same output after invoking `pkg-config ibus-1.0 --libs`. Should I install ibus 1.0 to build that library? If yes, where can I find it? It doesn't seem to be present [in ibus's downloads list](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)?

My OS is Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it for a build, then you need the `#include` headers as well.  These, and the `pkgconfig` files, are not in the normal packages because they don't serve any purpose outside of compiling.  Instead, they are included in separate `-dev` packages which you can install if you want to build something which must be compiled against whatever library.

It looks to me (on Debian) like the package you want is `libibus-1.0-dev`.

Comment: I've so far been unable to locate the `ibus` lib headers packaged for RHEL/OEL.

Comment: @javabrett Try `yum provides "*/ibus-1.0.pc"`.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, `yum provides "*/ibus*"` yields `ibus-devel-1.3.4-6.el6.x86_64`.